# Run-Time error '3075' when using sql UPDATE SET FROM WHERE

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I probably did a simple syntax error. but I couldn't find anything similar on the web so I'm asking you guys here.

I'm trying to update a field to 'true' if there is a match between two columns in two different tables, for example

```
Table1: CAT SELECTED    Table2: CAT
         1   FALSE               2
         2   FALSE               3
```

then the "selected" field for "2" will be changed to TRUE:

```
Table1: CAT SELECTED    Table2: CAT
         1   FALSE               2
         2   TRUE                3
```

I'm using the following sql code:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.SELECTED=-1 " & _
              "FROM Table2, Table1 " & _
               "WHERE Table1.CAT=Table2.CAT"
```

And I'm getting error '3075' that say:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '-1 FROM Table2'.
```

When I'm removing the `FROM` statement, the problem disappear, but then I'm just writing the values from `table2` manually.

Hope you can help,
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it by doing:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Table1, Table2 SET Table1.SELECTED=-1 " & _
             "WHERE Table1.CAT=Table2.CAT"
```

though I'm not actually updating Table2, adding it after "UPDATE" solved the problem.
If you have better ideas, I would like to know.